# I have this error with pygame , when i try to run code from Python Crash Course (Exception has occurred: AttributeError )

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a project from the book Python Crash course. I made everything exactly as the code snippets from the book shows but i constantly get the following error :

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'Settings' object has no
>   attribute 'screenWidth'   File "D:\Visual Studio Code projects\Sudoku
>   game\window.py", line 12, in run_game
>       (igSettings.screenWidth, igSettings.screenHeight))   File "D:\Visual Studio Code projects\Sudoku game\window.py", line 28, in
>   
>       run_game()

This is the code for my Sudoku file:

```
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings

def run_game():
    pygame.init()

    igSettings = Settings()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (igSettings.screenWidth, igSettings.screenHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Sudoku")

    while True:

        screen.fill(igSettings.bgColor) 

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit(0) 



        pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

And this is the code from my Settings file:

```
class Settings():

    def set(self):

        self.screenWidth = 1200
        self.screenHeight = 800   
        self.bgColor = (0.235,0)
```

I coulden't find a solution online

Comment: `igSettings = Settings();igSettings.set()` The attributes are set after you call `set()` function.

Comment: Please put stack traces in code quotes, and copy the stack trace exactly as it is. Helps us read them.

Comment: Thank you @Ch3steR , coulden't find the answer online and in the book this was not mentioned in the project chapter or the functions chapter. How do i mark that your answer worked tho ?

Comment: Glad to have helped. Posted an answer with little more details. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `set` on the object `igSettings` to set attributes of the object.

```
igSettings = Settings()
igSettings.set()
```

Or simply make them class attributes, you access them directly now.

```
class Settings:
    screenWidth = 1200
    screenHeight = 800
    bgColor = (0.235,0)
```

Now you don't even need to call `set`. You can look more about how [`classes`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) work in python.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the method `set`, create a constructor (`__init__`), in the class `Settings`:

```py
class Settings():

    def __init__(self):

        self.screenWidth = 1200
        self.screenHeight = 800   
        self.bgColor = (0, 235, 0)
```

Note, you cannot choose the name of the constructor. The name has to be exactly `__init__`. See [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).
The constructor is automatically invoked, when an instance of the class is constructed:

> ```py
> igSettings = Settings()
> ```

---

Further more there is a typo, when the attribute `` is declared (`.` -> `,`):

<s>`self.bgColor = (0.235,0)`</s>

```py
self.bgColor = (0,235,0)
```